# Too many connection logs in Mongdodb.log file

Tags: mongodb, logging, mongoose, connection

**These are the logs I got in mongodb.log file and there are thousands of these lines consecutively. I am using mongoose in Nodejs to make connection. Is this normal or a problem? What can possibly be the problem here:**

```
2019-07-25T02:57:44.341+0000 I NETWORK [conn77174] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59588 conn77174: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:45.713+0000 I NETWORK [conn77176] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59594 conn77176: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:47.096+0000 I NETWORK [conn77178] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59600 conn77178: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:48.467+0000 I NETWORK [conn77180] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59606 conn77180: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:49.846+0000 I NETWORK [conn77182] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59612 conn77182: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" }
 2019-07-25T02:57:51.208+0000 I NETWORK [conn77184] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59618 conn77184: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:52.571+0000 I NETWORK [conn77186] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59624 conn77186: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:53.945+0000 I NETWORK [conn77188] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59630 conn77188: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:55.313+0000 I NETWORK [conn77190] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59636 conn77190: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:56.698+0000 I NETWORK [conn77192] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59642 conn77192: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
2019-07-25T02:57:58.172+0000 I NETWORK [conn77194] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:59648 conn77194: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.6" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.4.0-131-generic" }, platform: "Node.js v8.12.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.5" } 
and the list goes on thousands of lines...
```

See this image for more:
[Mongodb.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahjax.png)

Comment: `received client metadata from` usually means a new connection is opened. Are you using a connection pool? If so, what is your pool size?

Comment: I have not set any pool size explicitly. I assume mongoose sets it by some default value. There were more than 20 thousands lines in 1 day, is it possible to open this much connections?

Comment: ran this command >db.serverStatus().connections

and got this:
{ "current" : 16, "available" : 51184, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(102801) }